# How do I find a hidden folder using batch?

Tags: batch-file, hidden, directory, minecraft

I'm trying to make a minecraft batch program that will find and reset your minecraft. The problem is, I'm gonna be releasing it and  everyone will have different usernames, and not all of them will have Vista+ with Users under `C:\Users\Username`. Some will have it under `C:\Documents and Settings\Username` or something like that.

This is the code I already have.

```
@Echo off
set UserProfile = Jackson
set Find = Desktop
pause
FOR /D %%Find in ("C:\Users\%UserProfile%\") DO pause
```

That's what I have. Obviously its wrong, but I need some help. Yes I understand that above it should be `set /p UserProfile = Insert username here` if I'm going to go that route, but I have it for testing. I just can't get `FOR` to work. Am I using the wrong command? I've been trying to research on it but I can't find a working solution. Thanks for the help in advance!

P.S. If you don't know what hidden folder I'll be looking for its `C:\Users\Username\Appdata\Roaming\.minecraft`

I have this continual problem with executing FOR. In batch even with pause it closes the cmd window. If I do it manually without a batch script (out into cmd.exe) then it says `%%Find was unexpected at this time.` How can I fix that?

Comment: The reason the other users scripts fail is because they're assuming that you're putting them into A batch script, not the command prompt. Just remove one of the percent signs..

Comment: @ProfPickle can you please post the code. I'm noobish with new batch stuff. And I am putting it into a batch script, as you can see by the lines of code and me saying "I'm gonna be releasing it and everyone will have different usernames"

Comment: If you are executing a `FOR` command DIRECTLY from the prompt, then the correct syntax is `for ... %v in ...` If you are executing `FOR` as a line of a BATCH FILE, the syntax is `for ... %%v in ...`. Any reference to the metavariable (loop-control variable - `v` in this case) must follow this rule - from the prompt, single `%` and within the batch file, `%%`. The metavariable may only be a SINGLE LETTER and is CASE-SENSITIVE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, all you need is the `%APPDATA%` environment variable.  It'll work on XP, Vista, 7 or 8 (and I daresay probably Windows NT and 2000 as well).  `%APPDATA%\.minecraft` will translate to `c:\users\<username>\appdata\roaming\.minecraft` on Vista+, or `c:\documents and settings\<username>\application data\.minecraft` on XP-.

So, just use `%APPDATA%\.minecraft` (possibly quoted) wherever you need to reference the `.minecraft` folder.

See this page on [Windows Environment Variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) for more useful system variable names.

Comment: I have this continual problem with executing FOR. In batch even with pause it closes the cmd window. If I do it manually without a batch script (out into cmd.exe) then it says `%%Find was unexpected at this time`. How can I fix that?

Comment: @JacksonML: Loop variable names cannot consist of multiple letters. It should be the prefix (`%%` in a batch file and `%` at the command prompt) followed by exactly one character (typically letter, but digits can also be used, as well as some non-alphanumeric characters).

Comment: @JacksonML - What the french, toast?  How does `%APPDATA%` not solve all your problems?  Why do you still insist on using a `for` loop?  Are you saying the minecraft folder could be somewhere other than `%APPDATA%\.minecraft`, or are you trying to find a subdirectory within?  If so, what subdirectory?

Comment: @JacksonML: Seconding what rojo said. I was simply addressing the direct question in your comment and didn't realise that the loop was (most likely) no longer needed for this problem. Just use `%APPDATA%\.minecraft` as suggested in this answer.

Comment: @rogo I don't know. I mean sometimes people can have it stored somewhere else, but that doesn't matter now. I'll mark this as answered, but Andriy you answered a question that wasn't asked. That should help me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
FOR /D %%F in ('dir/a C:\Users\%UserProfile%\') DO echo %%F
```

Comment: Same problem posted in the answer above

Comment: Scratch that comment, it won't let me delete it.

Comment: As written, this won't work. You probably meant to change `FOR /D` into `FOR /F`. One other issue is the `dir` command. First of all, the switch should be `/ad`, not just `/a`. Also, it would be a better idea to add the `/b` switch so that `dir` returns only names. Finally, the `USERPROFILE` environment variable holds the full path to the user directory. Therefore you can't just append it to another path. (In fact, you could just use it on its own.)

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice at first that `UserProfile` was re-used by the OP, so please disregard my last point. The rest of my comment still stands, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ( ' dir /b /ah /ad /s \.minecraft ' ) do set target=%%i
echo %target%
```

where \ is the directory where you start your search.

Comment: Same problem as above, but it says `%%i was unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all of your answers! I figured out (thanks to @AndriyM) that you can only use 1 letter after %%. That was my problem as I was trying to do %%Find and I had to do %%F and change the variables. Thanks guys for helping out!